# How to style transactional email with email-inline.css

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates, css, transactional-mail

I am using Magento 1.9.1. I want to customize my Magento Transactional Emails. To do so, I duplicated `email-inline.css` and `email-non-inline.css` from base package into my customized package (into this path: \skin\frontend\mypackage\default\css ).

I made the necessary changes and I uploaded the updated css but the emails arrive with the same design as before, as if the system was unaware of my custom css.

What do I have to do?

Comment: Which files did you copy where?

Comment: Have you fixed this? I'm having this same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one thing you could try.

> **NOTE:** This will only work for email templates that include use the `{{var non_inline_styles}}` variable.

1. Create a file called `email-custom.css` and add all the custom `<CSS>` that you need
2. Upload this file to `skin/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTHEME/css/`
3. In your Admin Panel go to **System** > **Configuration** > **General** > **Design** > **Transactional Emails** and add the `email-custom.css` file to the `Non-inline CSS File(s)` field like in the image below (using commas to seperate files)
4. Save config and flush all cache

[image: Magento Transactional Email Custom CSS]

Answer (score 2):

What i did was adding {{var non_inline_styles}} on template content and then i added all my styles on the template styles.[image]

Answer (score -1):

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html

refer this for both non-inline and inline CSS for mobile templates.