# Add different email-inline.css for different stores

Tags: css, email-templates, invoice, magento-1.9.3.2

I am using magento 1.9.3.2.
I am using english and arabic stores.

I want to align different styles for both different Stores.

How to add different email-inline.css for different stores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added as different file in top of email template after the variable declaration as follows:
`{{inlinecss file="arabic-email-inline.css"}}`

Answer (score 2):

You can set it from admin
To set store vise css Go to **Admin -> General -> Design ->Transactional Emails ->Non-inline CSS File(s)**.

You can set css file based on multiple store, also you can set multiple files using comma.

For more information you can refer [How to style transactional email with email-inline.css](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71235/how-to-style-transactional-email-with-email-inline-css?rq=1)

[image]